# Is it necessary to hide a screen when creating a new one in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am building an auth system. If the user is authenticated I display a profile screen, otherwise I display a sign in screen:

```
if(isAuthenticated) {
    ProfileScreen()
} else {
    SignInScreen()
}
```

Each screen is a composable function. Now, I'm listening to the sign out event and:

```
if(userIsSignedOut) {
    SignInScreen()
}
```

As per my understanding, if the user signs out, I'm creating a new screen (`SignInScreen`) right on top of the other (`ProfileScreen`) screen. If the screens were activities, I have used `finish()`. Is it the same here? Should I do something similar here? Do I have close/hide the previous screen somehow?

Comment: You don't have to close or hide a screen if you just use if else or conditionally show different composables. Because it is drawing different screens for different conditions and states. It's not like creating another screen on top of other screens. But if you navigate from one screen to another by using a navigation component then it is a different scenario. You might have to use popup or popout according to your case.

Comment: @Rafiul Thanks for your comment. That's not only the first if statement. The first if statement for example creates the ProfileScreen, and right after that, if the user signs out, it creates another one. So there is nothing I should do? And no, I'm not using navigation. It's better if I implement navigation?

Comment: What the difference between `isAuthenticated` and `userIsSignedOut`? They look the same to me. Are you using these two in two different places of your app?

Comment: Yes, Navigation is much flexible to manage fragments navigation and back stack management.

Comment: @Rafiul `isAuthenticated` checks the status of the user when the app starts, while `userIsSignedOut` is triggered while the app is running and the user signs out. Makes sense?

Comment: @shobhan Is there any example of implementing my scenario?

Comment: check out [compose navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

Comment: @ArpitShukla `isAuthenticated` checks the status of the user when the app starts, while `userIsSignedOut` is triggered while the app is running and the user signs out. Makes sense? Is there any example of implementing my scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by `triggered`? They are just `Boolean`s, right?

Comment: @ArpitShukla `if(userIsSignedOut) { .. }` is inside a listener. So if the user signs out, this if statement is triggered. So a totally different if statement than the first one.